# How would I go about adding a checkbox to Google Sheets based on whether there is a value within either of 2 columns to the left?

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet for something and I've run into a problem in how I want a column to work.

I want the Column F to create/delete a checkbox if there is/isn't a value within the D or E columns

I'm a javascript noob, I've basically only created a minor menu mod for minecraft. Is anyone able to help me by telling me how to reference certain cells and whether it contains anything within my sheet to input a checkbox/clear the value?

Or help write the function if you're bored haha

I've included an example image below.

[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcYX4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add your sheet name and possible a condition on e.range.rowStart if you have header rows

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart>3 && e.range.columnStart<6 && e.value) {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,6).insertCheckboxes()
  }
}
```

Note: you cannot test this function from the script editor as it requires an event object from the onedit trigger. No trigger?No workie.

Comment: Thank you very much, I now understand how to reference the columns and sheets as well as how to insert checkboxes through the function. As well as having a working function. Thanks again!